# Django Models: Assigning ForeignKey object without saving to database

Tags: django, django-models

I have models below

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    a = models.CharField()
    b = models.ForeignKey(ModelB)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    c = models.CharField()
```

Is is possible to create an instance of `ModelB` without saving it, assign to `ModelA`?
something like below

```
obj_b = ModelB(c='1')
obj_b.save(commit=False)

obj_a = ModelA(a='2', b=obj_b)
obj_a.save(commit=False)

# change obj_b attributes in between
# change obj_a attributes in between

obj_b.save()
obj_a.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no it's not, because the ORM doesn't seem to pick up that `obj_b` has been saved, however that shouldn't be a problem, because all you need to do is assign `obj_a.b = obj_b` *after* saving `obj_b`. This should work:

```
obj_b = ModelB(c='1')

obj_a = ModelA(a='2')

# change obj_b attributes in between
# change obj_a attributes in between

obj_b.save()
obj_a.b = obj_b
obj_a.save()
```

(Note, `obj_b.save(commit=False)` is invalid and will raise an error.)